# for loop to name dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a large list data_all which includes 8 lists. Then I want to assign each sub-list to a sub dataframe. I know to do it individually. How could I use for loop or other loops to name the dataframe automatically?
below is what I have done individually.

```
data_1<-data_all[[1]]
data_1 <-data.frame(data_1)
names(data_1)
subdata_1<-data_1[,c("ChartID", "Average")]
subdata_1$group<-array(0)
library("reshape2")
redata_1<-reshape(subdata_1, idvar="group", timevar="ChartID", direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Can you provide your data with `dput(data_all)`?

Comment: 1) `subdata1$group <- array(0)` doesn't need `array()`; 2) `reshape` is a function in base R package `stats`, you don't need to load package `reshape2`.

Comment: This approach might work but need your data to verify:
`# nested list
lx <- list(a = list(x= 1:10,y = rep("a",10)), b = list(z = 11:20, aa = rep("b",10)))
#loop to get each sub list to a sub dataframe
lx2 <- lapply(lx,as.data.frame,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#make each sub dataframe its own object in global env
list2env(lx2, .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I will assume a list of lists, `data_all`, with several members.
Create the list of lists:

```
set.seed(8189)

n <- 8
data_all <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
    let <- sample(letters, n)
    cid <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 2)
    list(A = let, ChartID = cid, Average = rnorm(n))
})
```

That list's members are first coerced to class `data.frame` and then two of their columns need to be kept, columns `ChartID` and `Average`.

```
subdata_all <- lapply(data_all, data.frame)
subdata_all <- lapply(subdata_all, function(DF) DF[, c("ChartID", "Average")])
```

Then a third column, `group`, is added to each of these data frames.

```
subdata_all <- lapply(subdata_all, function(DF) {
    DF$group <- rep(1:2, 4)
    DF
})

subdata_all[[1]]
#  ChartID    Average group
#1       A -0.9363024     1
#2       A  0.2242357     2
#3       B  1.2298253     1
#4       B  0.2836537     2
#5       C -0.7367582     1
#6       C -0.2492191     2
#7       D  0.1573474     1
#8       D -2.0102011     2
```

Now, reshape all of the data frames from long to wide format in one go.

```
redata_all <- lapply(subdata_all, function(DF){
    reshape(DF, idvar = "group", timevar = "ChartID", direction = "wide")
})

redata_all[[1]]
#  group  Average.A Average.B  Average.C  Average.D
#1     1 -0.9363024 1.2298253 -0.7367582  0.1573474
#2     2  0.2242357 0.2836537 -0.2492191 -2.0102011
```

Comment: Can you explain why include "length.out=4" ? Thanks.

Comment: @DaniellZhu You caught me! `length.out` is a bug that works because R will recycle to the number of rows of the dataframe. I will correct it.